# Get array of values from iterative subtraction of subsequent values within the array

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array as follows:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Now, given a starting value, for example 100, I would like to calculate the array that is formed by subtracting the subsequent value from the result of the previous subtraction. That is, I would like to get the result of:

100 - 1, 99 - 2, 97 - 3

That is, `[99, 97, 94]`.

I have tried the following.

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([1,2,3])


def resta_iterativa(value):
    result = []
    for i in my_array:
        substraction = value - i
        result.append(substraction)
        return result
```

The goal is to achieve an efficient code that works.

Comment: I think the indentation of ```return result``` is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.ufunc.accumulate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
arr[0] = 100 - arr[0]
np.subtract.accumulate(arr)
```

Output:

```
array([99, 97, 94])
```